# EF Core 3.1.x : The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: entity-framework-core-3.1

EF Core 3.1.x:

I would not like to load all products in memory, which below queries do!
Guess what happen if i do have millions of products in table?

```
var products = context.Products.ToList();
products = products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("xxx")).ToList();
```

And below query throws
The LINQ expression 'DbSet-Product-
.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(
value: "xxx",
comparisonType: InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

```
var products = context.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("xxx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Related Issue on github: [#19087](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19087)

Can anyone help me out. how to filter data with server side evaluation with ef core 3.1.x?

Comment: A couple of remarks: 1. EF core 3 never switches to client-side evaluation, except, when necessary, in the final select of a LINQ query. 2. Your query can't throw that exception. 3. I fail to see how the github issue is related. -- So, is this really EF core 3 and if so, did you post the exact query throwing that exception?

Comment: Yes, this query var products = context.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("xxx")).ToList(); throws same error. I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.3.0.  For related issue on github: it's kind of same issue but building with Member Expression, which i have tried to but throws same error.

Comment: There isn't any way that p.Name.Contains("xxx") can be translated to "Name like %xxx%" and goes to sql server?

Comment: Which database is this? This runs OK with Sql Server (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer).

Comment: It's SqlServer!

Comment: @GertArnold You are correct, my query contains StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase which was throwing error. Just updated error query in question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EF Core does translate Contains for server-side evaluation - but not the overload that accepts StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase (or any other StringComparison).

[Closed issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20995)